Error: Unable to access jarfile cfm using manifest file
I started developing a User-Defined JavaBean by following these steps :

Create a directory for the new bean
Create a directory/folder like C:\Beans

Create bean source file - MyBean.java

import java.awt.*;


public class MyBean extends Canvas
{
public MyBean()
 {
 setSize(70,50);
 setBackground(Color.green);
 }
}



Compile the source file(s)
C:\Beans >Javac MyBean.java

Create a manifest file MyBean.mf



Manifest-Version: 1.0
Name: MyBean.class
Java-Bean: True



Generate a JAR file

C:\Beans >jar cfm MyBean.jar MyBean.mf MyBean.class
I got the following error :
==> Error: Unable to access jarfile cfm
Have you any idea in this problem ?
Thank you
